# Write contents of a variable to text file from array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express and for my computer science class I need to make part of a VB.NET program write a single integer held in a variable titled `id` to a new line in a text file each time a loop goes through. I have accomplished file creation so far using `StreamWriter` and "InsertNameHere".WriteLine(id). However, my `id` variable is supposed to change depending on a which image is in a specific picturebox on my form. To try to achieve this, I created an array using `Dim pic(14) As Image` then i set the image in each picturebox to be the image stored in each section of the array.
My Code:

```
Tile1a.Image = pic(0)
Tile1b.Image = pic(1)
Tile1c.Image = pic(2)
Tile1d.Image = pic(3)
Tile1e.Image = pic(4)
Tile1f.Image = pic(5)
Tile1g.Image = pic(6)
Tile1h.Image = pic(7)
Tile1i.Image = pic(8)
Tile1j.Image = pic(9)
Tile1k.Image = pic(10)
Tile1l.Image = pic(11)
Tile1m.Image = pic(12)
Tile1n.Image = pic(13)
Tile1o.Image = pic(14)
```

After that, i use a for loop to loop through the contents of the array and check what the name of the image is. Depending on the image, the "id" variable is given a different value, and then the streamwriter is used to open the file and write the value of "id" to it.
       Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(FilePath)
        fs.Close()
        Dim writer = New StreamWriter(FilePath)

```
    For terrainimage As Integer = 0 To 44

        If pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Grass Then
            id = 0
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Sand Then
            id = 1
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Water Then
            id = 2
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Corner_BLeft Then
            id = 3
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Corner_BRight Then
            id = 4
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Corner_TLeft Then
            id = 5
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Corner_TRight Then
            id = 6
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Down Then
            id = 7
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Up Then
            id = 8
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Left Then
            id = 9
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Pond_Right Then
            id = 10
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_River_Horizontal Then
            id = 11
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_River_Vertical Then
            id = 12
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_RiverEntrance_Down Then
            id = 13
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_RiverEntrance_Up Then
            id = 14
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_RiverEntrance_Left Then
            id = 15
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_RiverEntrance_Right Then
            id = 16
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Up Then
            id = 17
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Down Then
            id = 18
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Left Then
            id = 19
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Right Then
            id = 20
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_BL_CornerDot Then
            id = 21
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_BR_CornerDot Then
            id = 22
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_TL_CornerDot Then
            id = 23
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_TR_CornerDot Then
            id = 24
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_TL_DualCDot Then
            id = 25
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_TR_DualCDot Then
            id = 26
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Corner_BottomLeft Then
            id = 27
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Corner_BottomRight Then
            id = 28
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Corner_TopLeft Then
            id = 29
        ElseIf pic(num) Is My.Resources.Tile_Beach_Corner_TopRight Then
            id = 30
        End If

        writer.WriteLine(id)
        num += 1
    Next

    writer.Close()
```

Any help is appreciated! I looked for an answer for about an hour and a half before i gave up and finally decided to ask for myself! If you need any further explanation or would like to see all my code thats no problem and I am new to VB so nothing too harsh please!

Comment: Oh by the way! I do get output in my text file but its just zeros. This makes me think that either the contents of the array aren't being checked properly, or the contents of the array aren't being assigned properly. But i'm not sure.

Comment: I wish comp sci professors would teach students how to use the tools before trying to teach code.  Go google `Visual Studio breakpoints`.